# Where is the notepad icon located in the registry in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-registry, icons, windows-11

I want to change the default Notepad++ icon to the default notepad icon in Windows 11. But I can't find its location in the registry. How to find the default notepad icon path in Windows 11?

Default Notepad in Windows 7, the path is: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\DefaultIcon`. With value: `%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll, -102`. But in Windows 11 is no such path. There is only a path: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy`. And there is no `DefaultIcon` parameter.

I also checked all icons in `%systemroot%\system32\imageres.dll` and `%systemroot%\System32\Shell32.dll`. But the standard Windows 11 notepad icon is not there.

Comment: The standard notepad icon is and was inside notepad.exe. also you can not change the icon of an executable, only of the files that are configured to be opened by a certain program.

Comment: @Robert
But on Windows 7 I added to this path: `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\DefaultIcon]` this value `@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\imageres.dll,-102"`. And all files with extension .txt has the same icon as the default notepad in Windows 7. I want to do the exact same thing in Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Notepad icon is within the exe itself in Windows 11. You'll find it in one of the sub directories within "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps", which itself is a hidden folder. You'll also find Notepad within "C:\Windows" and "C:\Windows\System32", but those are older versions with an older icon that I don't think Windows 11 uses by default? No idea.